# Play Store keep crashing while updating apps on Nexus 5

Tags: google-play-store, 4.4-kitkat, crashes, stock-android, nexus-5

Ok so, I have a Nexus 5, stock, updated to last Android version.

When I update apps, some of them, while downloading the update, make the Google Play Store crash to home.
I start again the play store and I start updating them again: this time, no problem.

It's not a big deal, but the randomness is kinda annoying me.

Anyone has any idea on why this could happen?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Nexus devices have an ongoing problem with playstore funny thing is Google are aware of it but dont seem to be able to fix the issues. I've had an similar issue with a Nexus 4 but I just downloaded an app called Aptoide to get my apps from and avoided the Play store altogether. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with my Nexus 4 using the Android Runtime (ART). It seems to be related to ART and/or the new "differential updates" that the Play Store now allows. Most app updates will now only download the updated files and resources in the APK. If a crash happens on an update, it will always occur during the gap between when the updated files are downloaded and when the installation starts.

If you're using ART, try switching back to Dalvik.

Comment: Not using ART, actually.